# ML Engine: Prediction Error while executing local predict command

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I have uploaded a version of the model in the Google ML Engine with `saved_model.pb` and a variables folder. When I try to execute the command:

```
gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir=saved_model --json-instances=request.json
```

It shows the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.local.predict) 2018-09-11 19:06:39.770396: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] 
Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/ml_engine/local_predict.py", line 172, in <module>
    main()
  File "lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/ml_engine/local_predict.py", line 167, in main
    signature_name=args.signature_name)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/ml_sdk/cloud/ml/prediction/prediction_lib.py", line 106, in local_predict
    predictions = model.predict(instances, signature_name=signature_name)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/ml_sdk/cloud/ml/prediction/prediction_utils.py", line 230, in predict
    preprocessed = self.preprocess(instances, stats=stats, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/ml_sdk/cloud/ml/prediction/frameworks/tf_prediction_lib.py", line 436, in preprocess
    preprocessed = self._canonicalize_input(instances, signature)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/ml_sdk/cloud/ml/prediction/frameworks/tf_prediction_lib.py", line 453, in _canonicalize_input
    return canonicalize_single_tensor_input(instances, tensor_name)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/ml_sdk/cloud/ml/prediction/frameworks/tf_prediction_lib.py", line 166, in canonicalize_single_tensor_input
    instances = [parse_single_tensor(x, tensor_name) for x in instances]
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/ml_sdk/cloud/ml/prediction/frameworks/tf_prediction_lib.py", line 162, in parse_single_tensor
    (tensor_name, list(x.keys())))


cloud.ml.prediction.prediction_utils.PredictionError: Invalid inputs: Expected tensor name: inputs, got tensor name: [u'inputs', u'key']. (Error code: 1)
```

My `request.json` file is

```
{"inputs": {"b64": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAHVArwDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBA....."}, "key": "841bananas.jpg"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your model was exported with only one input named "inputs". In that case, you shouldn't be sending "key" in the JSON, i.e., (scroll to the end to see I've removed "keys"):

```
{"inputs": {"b64": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAHVArwDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBA....."}}
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error     {
  "error": "Prediction failed: Error processing input: Expected uint8, got '\\xff\\xd8\\xff\\xe0\\x00\\x10JFIF\\x00\\x01\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x01\\x00....' of type 'str' instead."      }

Comment: To directly solve the issue, I'd need to know a bit more about the exported model, but it *appears* that the model is expecting an array of `uint8`, e.g. {"inputs": [[255, 255, 0, 64 ...], [0, 0, 33, ...]]}. That's not a terribly efficient way to encode images, so you might consider changes to how it's exported. It would be helpful if you update your original question with the output of `saved_model_cli show --all --dir /path/to/model`

Comment: Thank It is solved.While exporting the paramter should be encoded_image_tensor.I changed its working perfectly thanks